# Google claims my page isn't indexed, but it shows up in search results. Why does this occur?

Tags: google-search-console

Google claims my page isn't indexed, but it shows up in search results. Why does this occur?

I have a page showing up in Google search console as, "Crawled - currently not indexed" however, when I search for the terms on Google that very page shows up, why does this occur?

The page in question: https://ncservo.com/index.php/product/moog-17-136f/ shows up in the crawled but currently not indexed category of Google search console. However, when I go onto google and type in, "Moog 17 136f", it shows up first.

Is this caused by some sort of delay between GSC and live results?
Does this mean GSC is a generalized answer?

Comment: There is often a lag in the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reports in Search Console are always delayed.

1. You can check on the top right corner, when the report is last updated on.
2. For the current URL, you can see the "Last Crawl" to understand when the report is being shown for that particular URL.